# how to Improving relevancy in elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

This is how my mapping looks

```
$arr = [
        'index' => 'test1',
        'body' => [
            'settings' => [
               'analysis' => [
                    'analyzer' => [
                        'name_analyzer' => [
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => [
                              'lowercase',
                              'asciifolding',
                              'word_delimiter'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "mappings" => [
                "info" => [
                    "properties" => [
                        "Name" => [// this field is analyzed
                            "type" => "string",
                            "fields" => [
                                "raw" => [ //subfield of Name is not analyzed so that we can avoid a known issue of space saperated bucket generation
                                    "type" => "string",
                                    "index" => "not_analyzed"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "Address" => [
                            "type" => "string",
                            "index" => "analyzed",
                            "analyzer" => "name_analyzer"
                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

And this is my query

```
$query['index'] = 'test1';
    $query['type']  = 'info';
    //without bool & should also it will  work
    $query['body'] = [
        'query'=> [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    'query_string' => [
                        'fields' => ['Name'],
                        'query' => 'sa*',
                        'analyze_wildcard' => 'true'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'size'=> '0',
        'aggregations' => [
            'actor' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'Name.raw',
                    'size' => 10
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

My output is

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "actor": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Salma Hayak",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Salman Khan",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Salman Shaikh",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is since Salman Khan is the most searched actor as compare to Salma Hayak, having said that when user searched for "sa" they should see salman khan first rather than salma hayak.

Can anyone please help me on this?